# CA2000 StyleCop error message in processing XML string with XmlReader and StringReader

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, stylecop

I use StringReader and XmlReader to process string that has XML code.

```
private static string GetData(string jobResultXml, string pipeName)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(jobResultXml), settings);
```

It compiles/builds fine, but when I run StyleCop, I got this error message.

```
Error   6   CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In 
method 'ModelsimCommunicator.GetPipeData(string, string)', call System.IDisposable.Dispose 
on object 'new StringReader(jobResultXml)' before all references to it are out of scope.
```

What's needed for avoiding this StyleCop error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
private static string GetData(string jobResultXml, string pipeName)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

    using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(jobResultXml))
    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings))
    {
    }
```

The `StringReader` is `IDisposable` so StyleCop wants you to dispose of it before it goes out of scope. The `using()` does that. Also while you're there, you might as well use a `using()` for the `XmlReader`, because that's `IDisposable` too :)